# Установка Xamarin приложения на iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, apk, mobile

Условие:

1. Разрабатываю кроссплатформенное приложение. Xamarin Visual Studio 2019.
2. Под публикация для Android - все понятно, крафтим апк и в путь.

Вопрос:
Например, я хочу установить это приложение на iOS чисто для своих нужд. Не хочу публиковать в AppStore и тд и тп, как я могу это сделать? Есть ли аналог apk файла для iOS чтобы просто скачал и установил?

Comment: Некоторое время назад я тоже разбирался с этим вопросом. То что вы ищите это Ad Hoc, но все не просто, как обычно у Apple :-) вот какими материалами я пользовался https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=windows  
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows  
 https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99254/how-to-install-ipa-file-for-ios-iphone-ipad-ipod-appletv

Comment: @ПавелПопов а данные материалы учитывают то, что у меня нет устройств Mac/iPhone? Спасибо)

Comment: Забавный вы чувак) это не материалы, а вы должны учитывать, что входя в веселый и увлекательный мир Apple ваша жизнь сильно усложнится) Во первых вы ничего не скомпилируете без Mac или его эмулятора. Во вторых, что бы хотя бы протестировать на реальном устр. вы должны его зарегить и прописать в сертификат Ad-Hoc и попутно решить кучу гемороя связанного с Xamarin  Ну как говорится Welcome to hell:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак начнём с главного: **вам нужен Mac**, без него просто нельзя собрать *ipa* файл (аналог *apk* на андройде)

Если мак есть и нужно "просто запустить на симуляторе", то никаких проблем с этим не будет.

Если хотите запустить на *iPhone* потребуется аккаунт в *apple developer* для того чтобы сгенерировать *Provisioning Profile*. Как это сделать, лучше [этого гайда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/) я вам не подскажу.

Далее, когда вы настроили профайл и установили его на мак вы выбираете установить по проводу на телефон или собрать ipa файл.

1. **Телефон**. Просто подключаем телефон по проводу, выбираем Debug-iPhone и запускаем проект
2. **ipa**. В Visual Studio выбираете Archive for publishing, следуем инструкции. Он собирает ипа файл который можно установить на телефон с помошью различных тулзов. Лично я пользуюсь AppCenter (бесплатно)